# How can I test that my before_save callback does the right thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a callback on my ActiveRecord model as shown below:

```
  before_save :sync_to_external_apis

  def sync_to_external_apis                                                                                                 
    [user, assoc_user].each {|cuser|
      if cuser.google_refresh
        display_user = other_user(cuser.id)
        api = Google.new(:user => cuser)
        contact = api.sync_user(display_user)
      end
    }
  end
```

I would like to write an rspec test which tests that calling save! on an instance of this model causes sync_user to be called on a new Google instance when google_refresh is true. How could I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mocha is the way to go.  I'm not familiar with rspec, but this is how you would do it in test unit:

```
def test_google_api_gets_called_for_user_and_accoc_user
    user = mock('User')                  # define a mock object and label it 'User'
    accoc_user = mock('AssocUser')       # define a mock object and label it 'AssocUser'

    # instantiate the model you're testing with the mock objects
    model = Model.new(user, assoc_user)

    # stub out the other_user method.  It will return cuser1 when the mock user is 
    # passed in and cuser2 when the mock assoc_user is passed in
    cuser1 = mock('Cuser1')
    cuser2 = mock('Cuser2')
    model.expects(:other_user).with(user).returns(cuser1)
    model.expects(:other_user).with(assoc_user).returns(cuser2)


    # set the expectations on the Google API
    api1 - mock('GoogleApiUser1')          # define a mock object and lable it 'GoogleApiUser1'
    api2 - mock('GoogleApiUser2')          # define a mock object and lable it 'GoogleApiUser2'

    # call new on Google passing in the mock  user and getting a mock Google api object back
    Google.expects(:new).with(:user => cuser1).returns(api1)
    api1.expects(:sync_user).with(cuser1)

    Google.expects(:new).with(:user => cuser2).returns(api2)
    api2.expects(:sync_user).with(cuser2)

    # now execute the code which should satisfy all the expectations above
    model.save!
end
```

The above may seem complicated, but it's not once you get the hang of it.  You're testing that when you call save, your model does what it is supposed to do, but you don't have the hassle, or time expense of really talking to APIs, instantiating database records, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
it "should sync to external apis on save!" do
  model = Model.new
  model.expects(:sync_to_external_apis)
  model.save!
end
```

As an aside, requesting unreliable resources like the internet during the request-response cycle is a bad idea. I would suggest creating a background job instead.

Comment: Thanks. That tests if sync_to_external_apis is called at all. But how can I test the actual functionality of that callback? I need to check that api.sync_user is called under the right conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for testing is to ensure the results are as expected. Since you're using an API in this case that may complicate things. You may find that using [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) to create a mock object you can send API calls would allow you to substitute the `Google` class with something that works just as well for testing purposes.

A simpler, yet clunkier approach is to have a "test mode" switch:

```
def sync_to_external_apis
  [ user, assoc_user ].each do |cuser|
    if (Rails.env.test?)
      @synced_users ||= [ ]
      @synced_users << cuser
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end

def did_sync_user?(cuser)
  @synced_users and @synced_users.include?(cuser)
end
```

This is a straightforward approach, but it will not validate that your API calls are being made correctly.

Comment: Having a switch in production code for testing is a terrible idea. -1

Comment: I did say it was a clunky, sub-optimal approach. In a pragmatic sense, though, there are some things that will need to be disabled in the test environment, so you may need to resort to things like this unless you can re-engineer the implementation to avoid such dependencies. Having a an application-level switch `sync_to_api?` is certainly a step in the right direction. That sort of thing is a few levels removed from the original question, though.

Comment: And you should disable them *in* the test environment. Your production environment should never know anything about your test environment. Ever. TDD will help prevent such design smells.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the best way is to disable it from the tests. It feels like I need to use a different, maybe mocked/stubbed Google class from the tests, but not sure if that's possible.

Comment: One way around a lot of this mess is to make a module wrapper for the Google class that does the sync for you through a series of helper methods. You could define a method like `Refresher::Google.updateuser` to handle the calls, then have that configurable to avoid conflicts in the test environment. This is like how ActionMailer has a different mode for testing.

Comment: true to be told, production will never know anything about test env precisely because of the condition test `Rails.env.test?`